# Angular 2 - How to apply some condition to the ng-valid class when using ngModel

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have a select tag with the required attribute and a ngModel attached to it. There are three class that represent the states of the tag at the begining when the ngModel persist: ng-untouched, ng-pristine, and **ng-valid** (this is my question)

I want the ng-invalid class, not the ng-valid. The ng-invalid shows up when the value of a ngModel if null (or empty) but not with some custom values like 0 or 0< i think.

Here is my template code:

```
<label for="company-country">
  <span>Country</span>
</label>
<select id="company-country" name="company-country" required
    [(ngModel)]="currentCompany.location">   
  <option [value]="0" selected>Country</option>  
  <option [value]="1">Canada</option>
   ...
</select>
```

I'm setting the first option (**Country**) as a default value, so the first value of **currentCompany.location** is 0. I want the ngModel ignore that value applying some kind of condition so the ng-invalid class can show up. Is that possible? or i'm just missing something.

Comment: Just use an empty value for the first option: `<option value="">Country</option>`. Also, DO NOT add the `selected` attribute yourself. Angular will automatically select the option that matches the value of your model `currentCompany.location`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the user not to select the default one (country), you can use disabled attribute on the first option as below

```
<select id="company-country" name="company-country" required 
        [(ngModel)]="currentCompany.location">   
  <option [value]="0" disabled selected>Country</option>  <!--here is the change-->
  <option [value]="1">Canada</option>    
</select>
```

By this way the default selected one **Country** can **never be selected once the user has touched the select element**.

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/GZnINEzQJFwuLik2BP3C?p=preview)**

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a css class for ng-invalid as

```
.ng-invalid:not(form)  {
     border-left: 5px solid #a94442; /* red */
}
```

And as @AngularFrance mentioned in the comments you need to have a option tag with empty value as

```
<label for="company-country">
  <span>Country</span>
</label>
<select id="company-country" name="company-country" required
    [(ngModel)]="currentCompany.location">   
  <option [value]="" >Select</option>  
  <option [value]="0" >Country</option>  
  <option [value]="1">Canada</option>
   ...
</select>
```

So whenever the user selects the "Select" option ng-invalid class will get added automatically.

Comment: have a look at my answer below

Comment: your answer is correct.but I am not sure if it addresses the question.

Comment: what is your expectation then? elaborate it and I will update the post